# Where can I find videos to download in different resolutions

Tags: video, computer-vision

I am looking for (and not sure there is such a thing...) a database for videos where I could search for videos and download them by their resolution, length and other technical attributes.

The reason I ask is that I'd like to test some computer vision algorithm on different types of data.

Comment: What do you need that youtube doesn't offer? you can get most videos in several resolutions, and I'm sure scraping it can be automated.

Comment: Hello, I couldn't find a way to search for an exact resolution in youtube (I'd like to find a video of 200X200 pixels), also, I'd like to be able to choose the quality of the video (camera shakin or not etc.). Do you know of a db with examples for computer vision?

Comment: I'm not aware of any databases where video quality (other than a content rating) is available. Why don't you crop or scape some youtube videos to a resolution of your liking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a lot of stuff here : http://vasc.ri.cmu.edu/idb/ and in the links provided on the page.

You can make movies from images using [this](http://electron.mit.edu/~gsteele/ffmpeg/)

Comment: The last link there: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~cil/v-images.html had some images by resolutions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would write a script around a single (or maybe a few) selected videos and use `ffmpeg` to convert them to various resolution, bitrate, frame-rate, format as required to form the test data set.

Something along the lines of:

`ffmpeg -i source.avi -vcodec h263 -b 200000 -r 25 -s 240x160 test.mov`

Full info on ffmpeg [here](http://ffmpeg.org/faq.html) and [here](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html).

If you are particularly interested in testing a specific thing (always a good idea) - you can also generate "synthetic" video data using OpenCV (e.g. if testing tracking, create a blob moving on a known functional trajectory).